# Using jQuery to store basic text string in mySQL base?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, database

Could someone point me in the right direction here?
Basically, I've got this jQuery code snippet:

```
$('.bggallery_images').click(function () {
    var newBG = "url('" + $(this).attr('src');
    var fullpath = $(this).attr('src');
    var filename = fullpath.replace('img/Bakgrunner/', '');

    $('#wrapper').css('background-image', newBG);

    // Lagre til SQL
    $.ajax({
        url: "save_to_db.php",
        // The url to your function to handle saving to the db
        data: filename,
        dataType: 'Text',
        type: 'POST',
        // Could also use GET if you prefer
        success: function (data) {
            // Just for testing purposes.
            alert('Background changed to: ' + data);
        }

    });

});
```

This is being run when I click a certain button. So it's actually within a click handler.

If I understand this correctly, this snippet takes the source if the image I just clicked and strips it so I end up with only the filename. If I do an alert(filename), I get the filename only. So this is working ok.

But then, it does an ajax call to a php file called "save_to_db.php" and sends data: filename. This is correct right? Then, it does a callback which does an alert + data.

Does this seem correct so far?

Cause my php file looks like this:

```
<?php
require("dbconnect2.php");
$uploadstring = $_POST['filename'];
$sessionid = $_SESSION['id'];
echo ($sessionid);
mysql_query("UPDATE brukere SET brukerBakgrunn = '$uploadstring' WHERE brukerID=" .$_SESSION['id']);
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

When I click the image, the jQuery snippet fires and I get the results of this php file as output for the alert box. I think that the variables somehow are empty. 
Because notice the echo($sessionid); which is a variable I've created just to test what the session ID is. And it returns nothing. What could be the issue here?

Edit: I just tried to echo out the $uploadstring variable as well and it also returns nothing. It's like the jQuery snippet doesn't even pass the variable on to the php file?

Comment: OT, but your `var newBG = "url('" + $(this).attr('src');` line wants ` + ')'` at the end just before the `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to send *just* the filename, but you're retrieving a named form field in your PHP code. So you need to send a named form field:

Change your `ajax` call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "save_to_db.php",
    // The url to your function to handle saving to the db
    data: {filename: filename}, // <= Change #1 (give jQuery a simple object)
    dataType: 'text',           // <= Change #2 ('text', not 'Text')
    type: 'POST',
    // Could also use GET if you prefer
    success: function (data) {
        // Just for testing purposes.
        alert('Background changed to: ' + data);
    }

});
```

Your PHP script will now receive a POST varible called `filename` whose value comes from your `filename` Javascript variable. (You can also use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to do this, but it's just a wrapper for `ajax` anyway...)

Passing a simple object into the `ajax` call is the easiest way to send fields to the server. jQuery will take the object and create the URL-encoded form data (doing all of the escaping for you) by using the object's keys and field names. So for instance, if you give it this object:

```
data: {a: 1, b: "testing one two three", c: 3}
```

...it sends this URL-encoded data:

```
a=1&b=testing+one+two+three&c=3
```

(Note how it encodes it for us.) More in the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs (but beware, at present what the docs say about array handling is wrong; see [this bug report](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6376) for details).

Comment: Also add `var_dump($_POST)` in your server side script for testing.

Comment: Ok, so this actually returns the filename :)
But only when I do an echo of the variable within the php file.
The session ID is not retrieved however. 

I can retrieve it from my index.php file easily by just creating a variable: $session_id = $_SESSION['id']; and when I echo this, the result is '2' which is my session ID. I cannot retrieve this from the save_to_db.php file. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, found that there's another php file that seems to hold the session ID. I just need to get around a header cache limiter error. But thanx! You solved this issue though! :)